# Display an embedded google map iframe with a marker on a certain latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

This should be possible right?

I've tried searching for this, the docs show a similar example where you can embed a map with a marker on a certain 'place', like so:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI&key=..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is there a way to show the marker but using latitude and longitude instead of a place without using the js api?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you use the ["place mode" of the Embedded API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode) you can use coordinates to place a marker:

```
<!-- New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002) -->
<iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.7127837,-74.0059413&amp;key=YOUR_API_KEY"></iframe>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_coordinates.html)

Answer (score 57):

No need for JavaScript code nor Google API key:

```html
<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.856737, 10.606619&z=15&output=embed" width="360" height="270" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Just replace the `q` variable values with your coordinates.

Note: this doesn't allow more than one point.

Comment: can i pass name of place also

Comment: You can. Check here https://www.mapsdirections.info/en/custom-google-maps/ In the 2nd field add address or place name and check html code (query part)

Comment: You now need to get an API Key but it's free